# VB.NET : How to detect a mouse click outside a focused control

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net.
I have a control ( for example a button , or a textbox ... or something else ) that has the focus.

I want to detect when the user click outside this control.

The click may be :

- On another control that can get focus ( for example a textbox... ).
- On another control that can't get focus ( for example a panel...)
- On the form.

**Is there any general method to detect this scenario : A control has the focus, the user click outside**.

Thank you !

Comment: do you mean `onClick()` ?

Comment: use `lostfocus()`..it detects when focus leaves from the control..

Comment: lostfocus doesn't do what I want because is the case when a control is focused and the user click on a panel for example that can't get focus , so the control remain focused and the event will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

Not built in, but I believe it can be done -- use AddHandler control.click on all of the controls except for the one you want to to know when the click was for something else.

```
Sub RegisterControls(cntrl as Control)
   For Each c as Control in cntrl
      AddHandler c.click, AddressOf Whatever
      If c.Controls.Count >0 Then RegisterControls(c)
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry , but I want this solution to be general for each control. So for each control that can have focus , I want this behavior : If this control has focus and user click outside this control I want to detect this event.

Comment: @alex: then you want the above as a starting point.  Whatever you do, you need to capture all click events somehow.

Comment: I'm thinking is there any way to capture a mouse click ( not click events for a specific control ) and to calculate if is not inside a specific control ?

Comment: @alex: there are ways to test to see if a mouse button is down, that is different from a click.  If you capture all click events, you can test and do what is appropriate if this or that control has focus.

Comment: what about windows Messages to intercept the click ? it's possible this ?